# How to add class to all li but not to clicked li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a `hidden` class to all `li` but not to the `li` which was clicked. How can I do this using jQuery?

```
<ul class="render-menu">        
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

```js
jQuery(".render_menu li").on('click', function() { 
  alert();
  jQuery(".render_menu").not($(this)).parent().addClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly note that your `class` in the HTML is `render-menu`, yet the JS was using `render_menu`. You need to make them consistent.

With regard to the issue, you're adding the class to the `parent()` of the `li`, ie. the `ul`, so *all* the child elements are being affected by the class. To fix this, use `siblings()` to get all the `li` elements you require before calling `addClass()`. Try this:

```js
$(".render-menu li").on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="render-menu">
  <li class="font-size">list 1</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 2</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 3</li>
  <li class="font-size">list 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd replace `$('.render-menu li')` with `$(this).closest('.render-menu').find('li')` (within the handler) in case there are multiple `.render-menu`s.

Comment: Using `$(this).siblings().addClass('hidden')` is better

Comment: @Mohammad Indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS code to below

```
jQuery(".render_menu li").on('click', function () {
            alert();

            jQuery(".render_menu li").not($(this)).addClass('hidden');

        });
```

You are comparing `ul`  instead of `li` to add class

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```js
$('.render-menu li').on('click',function(){
 $('.render-menu li').removeClass('hidden').not(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="render-menu">

    <li class="font-size">list 1</li>

    <li class="font-size">list 2</li>

    <li class="font-size">list 3</li>

    <li class="font-size">list 4</li>

    </ul>
```